# Why would one choose to declare and initialize a lexical variable in separate statements?

Tags: perl, variables

This is an excerpt from [`AnyEvent::Intro`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent%3a%3aIntro)

```
# register a read watcher
my $read_watcher; $read_watcher = AnyEvent->io (
    fh   => $fh,
    poll => "r",
    cb   => sub {
        my $len = sysread $fh, $response, 1024, length $response;

        if ($len <= 0) {
           # we are done, or an error occurred, lets ignore the latter
           undef $read_watcher; # no longer interested
           $cv->send ($response); # send results
        }
    },
);
```

Why does it use

```
my $read_watcher; $read_watcher = AnyEvent->io (...
```

instead of

```
my $read_watcher = AnyEvent->io (...
```

?

Comment: afaik no difference; likely just style

Comment: ShinTakezou: did you try it?  with strict?  Throwing 'Global symbol "$read_watcher" requires explicit package name' in the latter is quite the difference.  Even without strict, the lexical $read_watcher would be a different variable to the package scoped $read_watcher inside the coderef.

Comment: From AnyEvent::Intro:  The reason for this is a quirk in the way Perl works: variable names declared with "my" are only visible in the next statement. If the whole "AnyEvent->io" call, including the callback, would be done in a single statement, the callback could not refer to the $read_watcher variable to "undef"ine it, so it is done in two statements.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because the closure references `$read_watcher` and the scope at which `$read_watcher` resolves to the lexical only begins with the statement *after* that containing the `my`.

This is intentional so that code like this refers to two separate variables:

```
my $foo = 5;

{
    my $foo = $foo;
    $foo++;
    print "$foo\n";
}

print "$foo\n";
```